Use SageMath to find graph minors
I am using SageMath to search for graph minors. I tried the following code which is given at: https://doc.sagemath.org/html/en/reference/graphs/sage/graphs/graph.html#sage.graphs.graph.Graph.minor
g = graphs.GridGraph([4,4])
h = graphs.CompleteGraph(4)
L = g.minor(h)
gg = g.subgraph(flatten(L.values(), max_level = 1))
_ = [gg.merge_vertices(l) for l in L.values() if len(l)>1]
gg.is_isomorphic(h)

As expected, it returns True. I want to know if it can further show a certifying minor when it is True. I will be grateful if anyone could give me a hint. Thank you! Also please let me know if I am using the wrong forum to ask.

According to the documentation you linked, minor(H) returns "A dictionary associating to each vertex of $H$ the set of vertices in the current graph representing it." This is basically the model definition of a graph minor, where by a model I mean: a model of a graph $H$ in a graph $G$ is a function $f$ assigning to the vertices of $H$ vertex disjoint connected subgraphs of $G$, with the property that if $uv$ is an edge of $H$ then there exists some edge of $G$ joining a vertex in $f(u)$ to a vertex in $f(v)$. $G$ has a model of $H$ if and only if $H$ is a minor of $G$. In your code above, the variable L plays the role of $f$, and contains a list of connected subgraphs of $G$ that when contracted give you the minor h.
